# Javascript replace one or another

Tags: javascript, replace

I'm trying to make the `replace` function work when having one match or another. It's very simple as a logic so I'd like to have a very simple implementation.

I have tried:

```
var my_url = document.URL;
var tmpl = "?tmpl=component" || "&tmpl=component"; //This is the tricky part
location.href = my_url.replace(tmpl,"");
```

...but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting `tmpl` to be the value of the expression `"?tmpl=component" || "&tmpl=component";`, which will always evaluate to `"?tmpl=component"`, since it is the first truthy value in your or statement.

You can do this with regex in a number of ways:

```
my_url.replace(/?tmpl=component|&tmpl=component/, "");
my_url.replace(/[?&]tmpl=component/, "");
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining to me. I thought a logical OR would be efficient in this case.

Comment: @otinanai Not a problem. In case you aren't sure, there are some great use cases for setting a variable value based off a conditional expression; they're really helpful for avoiding errors. The expression `var val = myVal || '0'` is great for setting default values in case one isn't provided, or just choosing the first truthy value in a series of potential options. My personal favorite is `var val == myObj && myObj.myVal`. Because JavaScript logical expressions short circuit, if `myObj` is null/undefined, you will avoid a ReferenceError, and val will only be set if myObj exists.

Answer (score 3):

This is not how JavaScript works, [logical OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_.28%7C%7C.29) is useless here. One possible way is using [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```
location.href = my_url.replace(/[?&]tmpl=component/, "");
```

Here the `replace` method will replace any match of `tmpl=component` starting with either `?` or `&`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do two replacements:

```
location.href = my_url.replace("?tmpl=component", "").replace("&tmpl=component", "");
```

or you could use a regular expression: (recommended)

```
location.href = my_url.replace(/[?&]tmpl=component/, "");
```

`[?&]` will match either a '?' or '&' character.

Comment: Thanks for providing more than one answer!

Answer (score 1):

Best one is:

```
 var tmpl = (my_url.indexOf("?tmpl=component") > -1)? "?tmpl=component" : "&tmpl=component";
```

Comment: This is the correct method to my approach although I'll go with the regex way.